# Intel XDK frameworks

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, intel-xdk

I've been trying to develop a mobile app using the Intel XDK. the app is more of a quiz, and has about 200 questions (about 200 pages in this case)

I've used the App Framework before, it was easy but shocked me when the displays were not the same on different device platforms, it was black and white on my Xperia V. Now I switched to the Twitter Bootstrap, the display is amazing, all my designs are visible, the problem now is that it's too slow, very slow, especially switching from one page to the next, what might be the cause of this? and how can I solve it? (it's only fast on the emulator, but slow on my device)

Answer (score 0):

I did not use nor App Framework neither Bootstrap, but  I think the problem in the way how you do the pagination.

Instead of creating "static" page for each question (each framework can have its own way for do such things) I would rather display questions in the same dialogue window and when user tap "Next" just change the content of the dialogue.